# Javascript to show a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a hidden div when the conditions are met as seen below.

```
<script>
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
  if (location.country_code == 'AU') {
    jQuery.show(jQuery('#aus'));     
  }
});  
</script>

<div id="aus" style="display:none;">
<div class="bottomBar">

This..

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
  if (location.country_code == 'AU') {
    jQuery("#aus").show();    
  }
});
```

Please go through this: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: What will div#aus give? :)

Comment: @JoakimM: As OP is trying to show div `<div id="aus" style="display:none;">` I used `div#aus`. There is no difference between `div#aus` and `#aus`. Anyway edited. :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should wrap that in a `document.ready`, second you need to use this syntax for [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```
jQuery(function() { // Wait for DOM to be ready
    jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
      if (location.country_code == 'AU') {
        jQuery('#aus').show(); // Correct syntax for show method
      }
    });
});
```